# Way to sum specific data from a csv file containing multiple columns and give result in python dictionary

Tags: python

I have the following parsed data from a csv file in the format of job, assembly, nodeLabel, x,y,z

```
data = [['j1', 'ass1', 1, [0.01, 0.01, 0.01]],
 ['j1', 'ass1', 2, [0.02, 0.02, 0.02]],
 ['j1', 'ass1', 3, [0.03, 0.03, 0.03]],
 ['j1', 'ass2', 1, [0.04, 0.04, 0.04]],
 ['j1', 'ass2', 2, [0.05, 0.05, 0.05]],
 ['j1', 'ass2', 3, [0.06, 0.06, 0.06]],
 ['j2', 'ass1', 1, [0.07, 0.07, 0.07]],
 ['j2', 'ass1', 2, [0.08, 0.08, 0.08]],
 ['j2', 'ass1', 3, [0.09, 0.09, 0.09]],
 ['j2', 'ass2', 1, [0.1, 0.1, 0.1]],
 ['j2', 'ass2', 2, [0.11, 0.11, 0.11]],
 ['j2', 'ass2', 3, [0.12, 0.12, 0.12]],
 ['j3', 'ass1', 1, [0.13, 0.13, 0.13]],
 ['j3', 'ass1', 2, [0.14, 0.14, 0.14]],
 ['j3', 'ass1', 3, [0.15, 0.15, 0.15]],
 ['j3', 'ass2', 1, [0.16, 0.16, 0.16]],
 ['j3', 'ass2', 2, [0.17, 0.17, 0.17]],
 ['j3', 'ass2', 3, [0.18, 0.18, 0.18]]]
```

Now I need to add job based (j1, j2, j3) x, y, z coordinates for each assembly and nodeLabel and output as -

```
{'ass1': {1:[j1x+j2x+j3x, j1y+j2y+j3y, j1z+j2z+j3z], 2: [j1x+j2x+j3x, j1y+j2y+j3y, j1z+j2z+j3z], 3: [...]}, 'ass2': {....}}
```

**Edit - added part of code I came up with

```
from collections import defaultdict

csv_content = data

jobDict = defaultdict(list)
for line in csv_content:
    jobDict[line[0]].append(line[1:])

final = defaultdict(dict)
# create assembly dict from job
for ks_j, vs_j in jobDict.items():
    # print(ks_j)
    assemblyDict = defaultdict(list)
    for v_j in vs_j:
        assemblyDict[v_j[0]].append(v_j[1:])

    # create node dict from assembly
    for ks_a, vs_a in assemblyDict.items():
        # print(ks_a)
        nodeDict = defaultdict(dict)
        for v_a in vs_a:
            nodeDict[v_a[0]] = v_a[1]
        # print(nodeDict)

        final[ks_j][ks_a] = nodeDict

print(final)
```

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to implement this feature” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  You have to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Hi, I will post the where the problem is, presently travelling back home. Thanks for your reply!!

Comment: This looks like a job for pandas.

Comment: pandas won't be an option, need to run in in Abaqus interface, therefore only bulit-in modules. I have edited the post with my code

Comment: Since `j1`, `j2`, and `j3` are strings and `x`, `y`,  `z`. are floats, I am not sure how you plan to add them. Are you expecting a string of `j1x` +` j2x` + `j3x` to be written into the list? Or do you know if `j1`, `j2`, `j3` are. also numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
data = [['j1', 'ass1', 1, [0.01, 0.01, 0.01]], ['j1', 'ass1', 2, [0.02, 0.02, 0.02]], ['j1', 'ass1', 3, [0.03, 0.03, 0.03]], ['j1', 'ass2', 1, [0.04, 0.04, 0.04]], ['j1', 'ass2', 2, [0.05, 0.05, 0.05]], ['j1', 'ass2', 3, [0.06, 0.06, 0.06]], ['j2', 'ass1', 1, [0.07, 0.07, 0.07]], ['j2', 'ass1', 2, [0.08, 0.08, 0.08]], ['j2', 'ass1', 3, [0.09, 0.09, 0.09]], ['j2', 'ass2', 1, [0.1, 0.1, 0.1]], ['j2', 'ass2', 2, [0.11, 0.11, 0.11]], ['j2', 'ass2', 3, [0.12, 0.12, 0.12]], ['j3', 'ass1', 1, [0.13, 0.13, 0.13]], ['j3', 'ass1', 2, [0.14, 0.14, 0.14]], ['j3', 'ass1', 3, [0.15, 0.15, 0.15]], ['j3', 'ass2', 1, [0.16, 0.16, 0.16]], ['j3', 'ass2', 2, [0.17, 0.17, 0.17]], ['j3', 'ass2', 3, [0.18, 0.18, 0.18]]]

def add(*crd):
    return [sum([c[i] for c in crd]) for i in range(3)]

result= {a:{n: add(*[x[-1] for x in filter(lambda y: (y[2]==n) and (y[1]==a), data)]) for n in set([k[2] for k in data if k[1]==a])} for a in set([r[1]  for r in data])}
print(result)
```